# How to linearize a quadratic objective function

Tags: quadratic-programming, linearization

I have an optimization problem. The objective is defined as follows:
 Max∑*(k=1)∑*(t=1)(r_k (t))^2 
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUhLM.png)
constraints are linear
How to linearize this objective function?

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-convex QP. There is a linearization possible based on the KKT conditions. This will give you a linear MIP. See [link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/06/solving-non-convex-qp-problems-as-mip.html)